# Pasting (with Command V) in input field on Mac

Tags: ui-testing

am writing feature file for UI on Mac.
I would like to enter Key.**Command** +'v' in an input field, using a feature file.
But I cannot see options for Key.Command in Key.java.

I see Key.SHIFT, Key.ALT, Key.CONTROL etc, but am not able to simulate the apple keyboard's **Command** Key.  Could you please advise on that?
Thanks :)